# Integrate Cordova-Sqlite 2 plugin into an existing IBM MobileFirst application

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to integrate the [cordova-plugin-sqlite-2](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2) plugin into my IBM MobileFirst application to be able to manipulate native databases from JavaScript.

I always encounter the same message "**transaction wait for open operation**". I think that I was not able to install the plugin correctly.

I've seen many tutorials that explain how to install plugins into an existing Cordova project but it's not the same structure.

So, my question is: What are steps to integrate this plugin to an existing MobileFirst application in which I already have an android environment?

Answer (score 1):

MobileFirst Hybrid applications do not support 3rd party Cordova plug-ins.

Your options are:

1. Using MobileFirst 7.1, create a Cordova app using the MobileFirst CLI, where your chances are higher for a successfull plug-in integration: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/08/18/developing-hybrid-mobile-apps-with-ibm-mobilefirst-7-1/
2. If using Hybrid is a must, you may attempt the following workaround for plug-in integration: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/

Migrating Hybrid apps to Cordova apps: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_migrating_cordova_project.html

Comment: Great, so it'll be easier for you to read the instructions I gave you.

Comment: But could you please explain what do you mean by "3rd party" Cordova plug-ins ??

Comment: Is the plug-in you mentioned developed by Cordova? No. It is thus a 3rd party plug-in. It was created by someone else.

Comment: aa ok ! My app is already created using MobileFirst Studio, I was using an other solution in order to pass data from js to native Now, I want to change the method by using sqlite .So, I can't recreate my app  :/   !!!!

Comment: Why not? I suggest that you will look into it. It is: 1) easy to migrate, 2) future-proof.

Comment: Migration: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_migrating_cordova_project.html